# grep or egrep does not properly match results from mailq containg a?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, regular-expression

I am trying to get the lines of held emails with grep or egrep that contain an exclamation point / bang

```
root@server:~# mailq

-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
0528561D88      878 Wed Feb  1 21:46:12  root@example.com
                                         root@example2.com

0D14161E2B      657 Wed Feb  x xx:47:01  root@example.com
                                         root@example2.com

0798C61E0F      657 Wed Feb  x xx:45:02  root@example.com
                                         root@example2.com

14AF361E2F!     657 Wed Feb  x xx:48:01  root@example.com
                                         root@example2.com
```

next

```
root@server:~# mailq |grep "[[:alnum:]]\!"
3658861E66!     657 Wed Feb  x xx:48:01  root@example.com
root@server:~# mailq |grep "^[[:alnum:]]\!"
root@server:~#
```

The first grep works provides the expected result,
but the second one does not work at all

Any thoughts?

Comment: `[[:alnum:]]` matches precisely one character. How many characters are there between the beginning of the line and the bang?

Comment: @don_crissti the expected print is 
`3658861E66!     657 Wed Feb  x xx:48:01  root@example.com`

Comment: @thrig 10 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `grep`ping for one alnum character followed by a bang.  Try the pattern `^[[:alnum:]]{10}!` instead.

Comment: grep did not work but egrep did the job

egrep "^[[:alnum:]]{10}!"

Comment: just tried out what you suggested out of curiosity but apparently it didnt work

`root@server:~# mailq | egrep "^[A-Za-z0-9]{10}!"
ED36761E87!     657 Wed Feb  x xx:40:01  root@example.com`

`root@server:~# mailq | grep "^[A-Za-z0-9]{10}!"
root@server:~#`

Comment: My mistake.  I shall remove my erroneous comment.

Answer (score 2):

The second regular expression, `^[[:alnum:]]!` matches a single alphanumeric character at the start of the line, followed by an exclamation point.

For example

```
3!
A!
c!
```

But not

```
14AF361E2F!
```

(ten alphanumeric character, and `!`)

To match exactly ten characters and `!`, use

```
$ mailq | grep -E '^[[:alnum:]]{10}!'
```